# Change keyframes-selector in @keyframes through a range slider

Tags: javascript, css, button, slider, css-animations

I'm a beginner in CSS, HTML and Java Script/jQuery. I actually do not code, but i found a solutiuon for my problem with a simple CSS animation.
I did not know, that the @keyframes animation still has some difficult stuff.

I am trying since days to code dynamic @keyframes. I have searched several threads for my problem. Some do sound similar to my,
but i just can not apply it into my code, it does not work..

I got the following code below in a code snippet. EDITED

```js
var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();
$.keyframe.debug = true;
var start = temp;
var start_100 = temp + 100;
var start_200 = start_100 + 100;

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrow21').resetKeyframe(function() {
      switch (animation) {
        case 'normal':
        $('.arrow21').animate({
        name: 'arrow21-move',
        '0%': start,
        '25%': start_100,
        '75%': start_200;,
        '100%': start
        });
    });
});

function play(animation) {
$('.arrow21').playKeyframe({
      switch (animation) {
        if document.getElementById("pha").value < 180 then
            case 'normal':
            name: 'arrow21-move',
            duration: "4s",
            timingFunction: 'linear',
            iterationCount: '100',
            direction: 'normal',
            fillMode: 'forwards',

});
break;
        else
            case 'reverse':
            $('.arrow21').playKeyframe({
            name: 'arrow21-move',
            duration: "4s",
            timingFunction: 'linear',
            iterationCount: '100',
            direction: 'reverse',
            fillMode: 'forwards',
          });


function pause() {
    $('.arrow21').pauseKeyframe();
}

function resume() {
    $('.arrow21').resumeKeyframe();
}


/* phase */
function myFunction() {
         x = parseInt(document.getElementById("pha").value);
         document.getElementsByClassName('arrow21')[0].style.left = x;
         document.getElementsByClassName('arrow21')[0].style.top = 460 + (80 * Math.sin(0.0111 * (x-20)));
         temp = 460 + (80 * Math.sin(0.0111 * (x-20)));
         document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = Math.round((x - 181) / 2.78);
         document.getElementById("print4").innerHTML = 460 + (80 * Math.sin(0.0111 * (x-20)));
}

/* amplitude */
function myFunction2() {
         y = parseInt(document.getElementById("amp").value);
         document.getElementsByClassName('arrow21')[0].style.height = y;
         document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = y;
         document.getElementsByClassName('arrow22')[0].style.height = y;
         document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + 100;
}

/* phase2 */
function myFunction3() {
         z = parseInt(document.getElementById("pha2").value);
         document.getElementsByClassName('arrow22')[0].style.left = z;
         document.getElementById("print3").innerHTML = Math.round((z - 181) / 2.78);;
}
```

```css
body {background-color: wight;}

h1 {color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: LM Roman 12;}

p  {font-family: LM Roman 12;
    font-size: 20px;}

.toggle{
 position: absolute;
 margin: -120px 150px;
  width: 300px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 font-size: 2.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}
.toggle:after {
         position: absolute;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
         width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #76011b;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background: green;
        content: "Start";
         z-index: 5;
}
.toggle:checked:after {
                       background: red;
                       content: "Stop";
}


.toggle:checked ~ #up-triangle1 {
                -webkit-animation-name: up-triangle; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                animation-name: up-triangle;
                animation-duration: 2s;
                animation-direction: forward;
                animation-iteration-count: 100;
                animation-timing-function: linear;

}

.toggle:checked ~ #down-triangle1 {
                -webkit-animation-name: down-triangle; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                animation-name: down-triangle;
                animation-duration: 2s;
                animation-direction: forward;
                animation-iteration-count: 100;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.toggle:checked ~ #rectangle1 {
                 -webkit-animation-name: rectangle; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                 animation-name: rectangle;
                 animation-duration: 2s;
                 animation-direction: forward;
                 animation-iteration-count: 100;
                 animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .arrow21 {
                  -webkit-animation-name: arrow21; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  animation-name: arrow21;
                  animation-duration: 2s;
                  animation-direction: normal;
                  animation-iteration-count: 100;
                  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .arrow22 {
                  -webkit-animation-name: arrow22; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  animation-name: arrow22;
                  animation-duration: 2s;
                  animation-direction: reverse;
                  animation-iteration-count: 100;
                  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.toggle:checked ~ #ball {
                  -webkit-animation-name: ball; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
                  animation-name: ball;
                  animation-duration: 10s;
                  animation-direction: reverse;
                  animation-iteration-count: 100;
                  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#up-triangle1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 320px;
   left: 168.5px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 15px solid transparent;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 45px solid #01ADAB;
}

@keyframes up-triangle {
           0% {top:320px;}
           25% {top:420px;}
           75% {top:220px;}
           100% {top:320px;}
}

#down-triangle1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 607px;
   left: 168.5px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 15px solid transparent;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
   border-top: 45px solid #01ADAB;
}

@keyframes down-triangle {
    0% {top:607px;}
    25% {top:707px;}
    75% {top:507px;}
    100% {top:607px;}
}

#rectangle1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 365px;
   left: 181px;
   height: 242px;
   width: 5px;
   background-color: #01ADAB;
}

@keyframes rectangle {
    0% {top:365px;}
    25% {top:465px;}
    75% {top:265px;}
    100% {top:365px;}
}

.arrow21 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 540px;
   left: 181px;
   height: 332px;  /* 332 */
   width: 5px;
   background-color: #80D0CF;
}

@keyframes arow21 {
    0% {top:320px;}
    25% {top:420px;}
    75% {top:220px;}
    100% {top:320px;}
}

.arrow22 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 320px;
   left: 681px;
   height: 332px;
   width: 5px;
   background-color: #80D0CF;
}

@keyframes arrow22 {
    0% {top:320px;}
    25% {top:420px;}
    75% {top:220px;}
    100% {top:320px;}
}

#print1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 111px;
    left: 182px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
}

#print2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
    left: 110px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
}

#print3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 151px;
    left: 182px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
}

#print4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>My Code</h1>
<hr>
<form>
  <span style="display:inline-block; height: 20px;"></span>
  <b><font size="4">amplitude:</font></b><br>
  <input type="range" id="amp" name="amplitude" oninput="myFunction2()"
  placeholder="0" min="156" max="484" value="320" step="1">
  <br>
  <span style="display:inline-block; height:20px;"></span>
  <b><font size="4">phase:</font></b><br>
  <input type="range" id="pha" oninput="myFunction()"
  name="phase" min="181" max="681" value="181" step="1">
  <br>
  <span style="display:inline-block; height:20px;"></span>
  <b><font size="4">phase2:</font></b><br>
  <input type="range" id="pha2" oninput="myFunction3()"
  name="phase2" min="681" max="1181" value="781" step="1">
</form>


<p id="print1"></p>
<p id="print2"></p>
<p id="print3"></p>
<p id="print4"></p>
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<div id="up-triangle1"></div>
<div id="down-triangle1"></div>
<div id="rectangle1"></div>
<div class="arrow21"></div>
<div class="arrow22"></div>

</body>
```

The animation with the Start Button (checkbox) works fine for me. This should also be the resume button to continue the animation, if it once started. The shapes are moving in a proper way. I could change the phase and amplitude during animation on my editor. In the code snippet it does not work. But thats not the primary problem.

My Problem is, i do not kwow how can i get the current value from amplitude and apply it as a start condition to the shape. It is a dynamic value because of the range slider.
This value changes the top position of the shape. The animation must begin from this current value shown at print1.

Like this:

From:

Amplitude value: Start value: 320.

```
@keyframes arrow21 {
    0% {top:320px;} /* start position */
    25% {top:420px;} /* moving 100px down */
    75% {top:220px;} /* moving 100px up */
    100% {top:320px;} /* end position */
}
```

To

Amplitude value: 400.

```
@keyframes arrow21 {
    0% {top:400px;} /* start position */
    25% {top:500px;} /* moving 100px down */
    75% {top:300px;} /* moving 100px up */
    100% {top:400px;} /* end position */
}
```

So if you change the value, the animation should change either and start from the same value where the range slider is.
I need an updated animation, so if the animation is running and the amplitude is changed, it should be directly updated. (or after clicking start/stop)
This should be possible for each value you set at the range. Also the animation should change from normal to reverse at the edge of 180 from phase range.

How can i achieve this? I tried already something, maybe it just have to be slightly modified.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally , @keyframes are inflexible as they are usually hard-coded.
There is a useful JavaScript Keyframe Library [Rekapi](https://jeremyckahn.github.io/rekapi/doc/) which you can check.

Besides here is a project on dynamic keyframes check this [link](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes).

Hope it will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have seen the first link already, but i could not apply it to my problem. I do not know how to install or to call the library. The second link also uses constant values in the animation, or did i misunderstand it?

I changed the code above a bit and i achieved, the change of the slider value to the shape. The animation runs with both shapes at the beginning, but one shape stops, if i change the amplitude value.

Comment: Have you checked the gitHub project ?

Comment: have you included jQuery.Keyframes in project

Comment: I hope so. I added this lines to my code.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src='/path/to/jquery.keyframes[.min].js'></script>

But I actually do not know where the jquerry code must be implemented.

Comment: path/to..... is just a example , include this in your.html like this 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.keyframes.js"></script>
browse to https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes/blob/master/example/index.html this location to see its implementation in html file

Comment: Now i am really confused.. I'm sorry. I read the keyframes.github.io/jQuery.Keyframes arcticle a few times and also tried to apply code lines. I did not have the right result.
I edited my code above. It is almost what i want to have, but the animation shell start with the Start button. What can I do?

Comment: So now i downloaded the example above. I added the local path of the jquery libraries. Even the example with the smiley-shape is not working. Can someone edit my code please, so i can see, what i would need to change? Thanks.

Comment: Can You create a fiddle or stackBlitz for same

Comment: I tried to implement the code above into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0c35n9q8/.
I use Chrome. The code aboves works with the range slider fine. I dont't know why seperating the code at jsfiddle into Javascript, HTML and CSS crashes the range slider. I hope you can help me.

Comment: <div id="rectangle1" class="arrow21"></div> , as from your fiddle (rectangle1 1st bar) is moving while second not on toggle. if you add the same id to class="arrow21" it will also animate.
i really didnt got the use of amplitude and phase slider in fiddle as its not changing anything in code

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but i tried several things.
So basicly i try to move a shape along a sine wave. With the range slider phase the shape moves in the x.-axes left and right. And it also has to change the hight, so it moves on a sine wave. The animation shell change from normal to reverse if the value of the phase slider is above 180. So it has to do something with an if-condition loop.

And as you said, the range sliders does not change anything. I code with the cssdesigner and if I copy the code above of my question into a new project and let it run in chrome, it does work perfect.